# Debugging Node.js disk I/O and CPU spikes

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, node.js

I'm running a Node/Meteor/Mongo app on Ubuntu (on a Digital Ocean 1GB droplet), and I've been seeing some weird disk I/O spikes, which are then followed by CPU spikes:

[image]

I was wondering:

1. If that pattern corresponds to any known problem?
2. What tools or strategies I could use to figure this out?

I'm pretty new at server and performance monitoring, so any help will be appreciated, no matter how basic!

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many reasons.

1. My first question would be does your memory spike at all in
   correlation to the CPU?
2. Do you have any known recurring jobs?
3. Do the spikes correlate to any traffic spikes or API usage?